# Prestashop 1.5.3.1 Cannot add items to Cart or Login to shop front

Tags: authentication, prestashop, cart

My website http://www.lordswoods.co.uk has two problems,

1. no products can be added to the cart,
2. customers cannot login to shop front.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the cart block and restoring the whole site to before the problem existed.

I have changed define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false); to define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true); in config/define.inc.php to show errors.

It seems to related to the header, anybody know what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error related to the headers in a common one on PHP : check if you don't have characters before the PHP open tag in your templates.

Also check the charset encoding of the files, if it matches UTF8 declaration in your HTML code.